# How to sort a list of vectors by direction

Tags: c#, sorting, math

How would one sort a list of Vectors (Preferably 3d) in a list by direction.
Not using distance.

I have a list of vectors. I have a vector direction.

[image: A getto image]

using my getto photo here as example. How would one sort a list/array of vector3's by a certain direction. Using distance won't work for the most part because I am using a direction rather then a sourcepoint.

so angle 1 would make = DCBA

angle 2 = CDAB

angle 3 = ABCD

Comment: Do you have any code to start with?

Comment: Just that which makes the list of points and direction. The points can be negative as well as positive, and the direction can be any which way. I tried to make a hacky distance version. But with the randomness of the points I can't seem to find a safe way to do it. I figure some high level math might help, but i don't know where to start with that.

Comment: How do you define single direction value for a 3D vector?

Comment: Your description of the problem requirements is unclear to me, and the diagram isn't helping. Can you [edit] the question and add a simple example (with numbers) and the desired result, and why.

Answer (score 1):

Give all those points an ordered tuple in 3-D space, use angle 1 to define a vector function by giving it an angle and an origin, minimize the distance between the vector function and a point in 3-D space and sort based off that minimum.